# Pentaho kettle Can't run transformation due to plugin missing

Tags: java, amazon-s3, pentaho, kettle

I trying to execute transformation file using java , transformation get data from database and print data to file in s3 by s3 output file step.it works fine when run by spoon ,but when trying to run in java application get the following error

```
Can't run transformation due to plugin missing
```

java code

```
    KettleEnvironment.init();
    URL ktrUrl = PipelineResource.class.getClassLoader().getResource(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    TransMeta transMeta = new TransMeta(ktrUrl.getPath());
    Trans trans = new Trans(transMeta);
    trans.execute(new String[]{});
    trans.waitUntilFinished();
    if (trans.getErrors() > 0) {
```

full stack trace

```
  2017/06/29 12:46:11 - S3 File Output.0 - ERROR (version 7.0.0.6-95, build
1 from 2017-05-23 03.01.13 by buildguy) : Can't run transformation due to
plugin missing2017/06/29 12:46:11 - S3 File Output.0 - ERROR (version
7.0.0.6-95, build 1 from 2017-05-23 03.01.13 by buildguy) : Error
initializing step [S3 File Output]
2017/06/29 12:46:11 - transformation1 - ERROR (version 7.0.0.6-95, build 1
from 2017-05-23 03.01.13 by buildguy) : Step [S3 File Output.0] failed to
initialize!
2017/06/29 12:46:11 - data from asset.0 - Finished reading query, closing
connection.
2017-06-29 12:46:11.048 ERROR 22396 --- [ XNIO-2 task-2] 
com.innvo.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exception in 
com.innvo.web.rest.PipelineResource.runPipeline() with cause = 'NULL' and 
exception = '
We failed to initialize at least one step. Execution can not begin!'
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
We failed to initialize at least one step. Execution can not begin!
at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.prepareExecution(Trans.java:1157)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.execute(Trans.java:627)
at com.innvo.web.rest.PipelineResource.runPipeline(PipelineResource.java:201)
at com.innvo.web.rest.PipelineResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$81033db7.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at com.innvo.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
```

Comment: yes,I have added all plugins by gradle but not work

Comment: You posted this exact same question 2 days ago [Pentaho get We failed to initialize at least one step. Execution can not begin!'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823715/pentaho-get-we-failed-to-initialize-at-least-one-step-execution-can-not-begin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works by add plugin path before

```
  KettleEnvironment.init();
```

add plugins path

```
  StepPluginType.getInstance().getPluginFolders().add(new PluginFolder("/home/ali/data-integration/plugins", false, true));
```

Comment: Added the line but it is still not able to find the pugin with id MetaDataInject.

Comment: This suppose to work, but in somehow is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It only worked when I did the following:

1) Added the following variables that points the data-integration plugin folder to the VM Arguments:

```
-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS=path_to_your_data-integration/plugin
```

2) this wasn't enough because my plugin folder was missing the mongodb jar, when I added the jar **pentaho-mongo-utils-8.2.0.0-342.jar**(beware the jar may vary according the version you're targetting) it worked.